# Odd failed request in Google Chrome console in AngularJS SPA

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I have an AngularJS single page application that sends and retrieves data from a C# Web API service. Both applications are hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. Periodically I get a failed request in the Google Chrome developer console. The request is to http://singlepageapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/null. It bugs me because I can't work out where it originated from. All Ajax requests in my application come from the same place, and always have the base URI (http://mywebapi.elasticbeanstalk.com/) with 'api/' and the name of the Web API controller appended.The developer console shows the following:

```
Request URL:http://singlepageapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/null
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

The raw request that causes the error is as follows:

```
GET /null HTTP/1.1
Host: singlepageapp.elasticbeanstalk.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Referer: http://singlepageapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/
Accept-Language: en
Range: bytes=0-1244
```

Chrome list the type as 'media' and the initiator as 'other'. Any ideas would be gratefully received. Huge thanks in advance.

EDIT: I just got the error again and noted that the request was not to my web api, but to the elastic beanstalk single page application. My logic makes no (direct) requests to this URI, all these are initiated by the browser in response to the user clicking a link. In this case the 'Save' button on one 'page' after a successful save runs the following:

```
$location.path('/next-page');
```

It is this that triggers the errant request. This doesn't occur though when going to this URI directly via clicking a link in the menu.

Comment: Can you list any of the Angular code that supposedly always hits `host + 'api/' + endpoint` for AJAX requests? Clearly one of those `'api/' + endpoint` calculations returned `null`, which got stringified as `"null"`.

Comment: @AustinMullins Huge thanks for your reply. I just noticed that the request in question is not to my web API, but to the single page application URI. That is, it is being initiated by the browser. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found the issue. The page in question allows the user to take a photo using their web cam. When they click the 'Save' button they are taken to another page. However before this occurs the logic does the following:

```
video.src = null;
```

where 'video' is the following element in the page:

```
<video class="cssimageclass" autoplay></video>
```

Setting the src to null initiated the browser request. Removing this fixed the problem.